# Jquery Accessing Parent function from child window

Tags: jquery

Parent Window Code(Sample):

```
 var myparentwindow = (function($,undefined){
                            window.add = function(a,b){
                                //my main logic goes here
                            }
                          })(jquery);
```

Child window Code:

```
$(function () {
    $('div.popp_dialog').each(function (i, el) {
        var paste = (new $.paste()).appendTo(el)
          .on('pasteImage', function (ev, data) {
              var dataUrl = getBase64Image(data.dataURL);
              var imageType = "image/jpeg";
              opener.myParentWindow.add(dataUrl, imageType);
              closeWindow();
          })
          .on('pasteText', function (ev, data) {
              alert("Pasted content is not valid.");
          });
        $(el).click(function () {
            $(paste).focus();
        });
        if (i == 0) {
            paste.focus();
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting an error when an trying to access like this `opener.myParentWindow.add(dataUrl, imageType);`
or

`window.parent.myParentWindow.add(dataUrl, imageType);`

How I access that 'add' function in my child window.

Comment: I believe you'll have to add it to your child window as a script.

Comment: What about `window.opener.add(...` or `window.parent.add(...` ?

Comment: Neither worked for me @ClaytonLeis